# Javascript unhide text element not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched around the internet but I still can't find a solution to my problem. The issue I have is that I have a HTML selectbox and a text box as follows:

```
 <p>
    <label for="car_parking">Issue a car park pass ?:</label>
    <select name="car_park_pass" id="car_park_pass" tabindex="<?php echo $tab++; ?>">
       <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
       <option value="yes">Yes</option>
       <option value="no">No</option>   
    </select>
 </p>
 <div id="reg_number">  
    <p>
       <label for="car_reg_no">Car registration number</label>
       <input type="text" name="car_reg_no" id="car_reg_no" tabindex="<?php echo $tab++; ?>">
    </p>
 </div>
```

The problem I have is that I want to display "reg_number" if "car_park_pass" is equal to "yes" but have it be hidden by default. I have the following javascript which I tried putting in the head and the body but nothing seemed to work:

```
 $('select[name=car_park_pass]').change(function() 
 {
      if ($(this).val() == 'yes') 
      {
           $('#reg_number').show();
      } 
      else 
      {
           $('#reg_number').hide();
      }
 });
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `$` before `('select[name=car_park_pass]').change`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('select[name=car_park_pass]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'yes') 
  {
      $('#reg_number').show();
  } 
  else 
  {
      $('#reg_number').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the html

```
<p><label for="car_parking">Issue a car park pass ?:</label>
 <select name="car_park_pass" id="car_park_pass" tabindex="<?php echo $tab++; ?>">
 <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
 <option value="yes">Yes</option>
 <option value="no">No</option>   
 </select></p>
 <div id="reg_number" style="display:none;">  
 <p><label for="car_reg_no">Car registration number</label>
 <input type="text" name="car_reg_no" id="car_reg_no" tabindex="<?php echo $tab++; ?>"></p>
 </div>
```

and here is the javascript

```
$( "#car_park_pass" ).change(function() {

      if ($(this).val() == 'yes') 
           {
                $('#reg_number').show();
           } 
           else 
           {
                $('#reg_number').hide();
           }

});
```

You can see it working here
http://jsfiddle.net/utn74a0s/

Answer (score 1):

this code works, the problem was using `.on()`

this jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#car_park_pass" ).on( "change", function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'yes'){
            $('#reg_number').show();
        } 
        else{
            $('#reg_number').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- You forgot the `$` symbol in this code `('select[name=car_park_pass]')`.
- In the last line, `});` , the brace is not open
- Call the change function when the document is ready, it's more efficient
- Select by ID si more efficient `$('#car_park_pass')`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="car_parking">Issue a car park pass ?:</label>
  <select name="car_park_pass" id="car_park_pass">
    <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>   
  </select>
</p>
<div id="reg_number">  
  <p>
    <label for="car_reg_no">Car registration number</label>
    <input type="text" name="car_reg_no" id="car_reg_no">
  </p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#car_park_pass').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'yes'){
        $('#reg_number').show();
      } 
      else{
        $('#reg_number').hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```